# How to return a value to javascript after posting via ajax (Jquery)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm sending data via ajax (jquery) to php where it will be processed. I'd like to return a value from the php script, but I'm not sure how.

How do I return the result back?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  //This script sends var Score to php
        Score=100; //Dummy variable
            $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "returnresults.php",  
            data: { 'Score':Score },      
            success: function(){  
            $('#box2').html(Score);
            } 
        })
    });
```

Very simple PHP CODE

```
<?php
$Score=$_POST['Score']; 
       if (isset($_POST['Score'])) { 
       $Score=80;
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies everyone! I've got to duck out for a bit, but I'll go over them all as soon as I get back tonight.Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PHP page should output the html or text that you want returned, so at its simplest perhaps add this to the end of your PHP:

```
echo $Score;
```

If you want to pre-format it a bit within your PHP then:

```
echo "<div>" . $Score . "</div>";
```

Where you can make the html markup as simple or complicated as appropriate (the `<div>` in this case being just an example, obviously).

Then your jQuery ajax call will automatically pass the response through as a parameter to your success handler, so:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "returnresults.php",  
    data: { 'Score':Score },      
    success: function(data){ // <-- note the parameter here, not in your code
       $('#box2').html(data);
    } 
});
```

(`data` will be the response).

Note: if you know that the only thing you want to do with the response from the ajax call is to take the data/text/html and put it into a particular element you can simplify things by just using the [jquery `.load()` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) instead of `$.ajax()`:

```
$('#box2').load("returnresults.php", { 'Score':Score });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a beginner so stating what php code I needed and what the data represented did it for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  In particular with respect to the `success` handler function:

> success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
>
> A function to be
>   called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three
>   arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to
>   the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR
>   (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.

So jQuery will pass three parameters to your `success` function.  The first one contains the data that you want.  If you just want to pass exactly what the server returns on into your `success` handler, you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  //This script sends var Score to php
        $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "returnresults.php",  
        data: { 'Score':Score },  
        dataType: "text",    //set the dataType to 'text' so that jQuery passes it verbatim
        success: function(newScore){  //the first parameter will contain the response the server sent, we ignore the other two parameters in this example
            $('#box2').html(newScore);
        } 
    })
});
```

And then in your PHP code, just write the desired value straight to the response.

Comment: I had briefly looked at that, but hadn't understood it's importance. Now that you have pointed it out it makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  //This script sends var Score to php
    Score=100; //Dummy variable
        $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "returnresults.php",  
        data: { 'Score':Score },      
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
            $('#box2').html(Score);
        } 
    })
});
```